# How to load resource from exe rather than dll

Tags: dll, mfc

I am loading a satellite dll which holds language resources. However I only want to store strings in the dll and not the dialog resources. I load the dll as below:

```
hInst = LoadLibrary( _T("MyAppFRA.dll") );
if (hInst!= NULL)
    AfxSetResourceHandle( hInst );
```

The problem is if I bring a CTestDlg now as below, it never comes up.

```
CTestDlg dlg;
dlg.DoModal()
```

It is because the dialog resource IDD_DIALOG1 is there in the exe but not in the dll so DoModal() can't seem to find it (as a result of `AfxSetResourceHandle()` call.) This is intentional, I thought if it didn't find the resource in dll, it will automatically look in exe but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Can I load the dialog from exe resource when rest of my resources are in a dll?

Comment: Do your dialogs not contain any text? Why wouldn't they be translated as well?

Comment: @MarkRansom They do, I want to load the texts from the current resource handle in OnInitDialog(). This way my dialog resource is shared and only texts get translated.

Comment: Sometimes the layout needs changing because the words are longer or shorter than they are in English. But if it works for you, I won't complain.

Answer (score 0):

We have a huge application with resources all over the place. You can use AfxSetResourceHandle() whenever you want to change the context of where MFC looks for resources. We have a stack based object that allows us to set the resource handle and then restore it.  AfxGetResourceHandle() is the function that gets the current value.

Comment: This works if you're willing to call AfxSetResourceHandle inside your OnInitDialog.

Comment: @MarkRansom This means I have to change the context back and forth and this would be many many places, kind of undesirable. I was going by [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fkteez0%28vs.71%29.aspx) where Microsoft says "If MFC does not find any satellite DLLs, it uses whatever resources are contained in the application itself." but I guess the emphsis is on  'not finding satellite dll' and not 'resource in the dll' so my interpretation was wrong.

Comment: Well, I have re-read your original question... I see that you are manually loading the DLL using LoadLibrary(). The AfxSetResourceHandle() stuff is designed to work for MFC extension libraries.  Did you build the DLL as an extension library?  That will make a difference in how MFC traverses the DLL resources.

If you setup the DLL as an extension library, the big problem with resources is not in being unable to find a resource, but duplicates. If you don't have duplicates of any resources, you never have to worry about calling AfxSetResourceHandle() because MFC should find everything just fine

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson Yes it is an extension dll but it doesn't find the resource.

Comment: Well, the next step I would take would be to open the executable/DLL in Visual Studio as a resource. I would then examine the resources in that compiled module to make sure that resource really was present.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the dialog template from the .exe resources yourself, then call `InitModalIndirect` to tie it to the dialog object. `DoModal` will use this resource rather than trying to load one from the current resource handle.